# How to automat sqlplus

Tags: oracle

So, other posts have show that basically you can inline sqlplus with

```
echo 'select 1 from dual;' 'exit' | sqlplus -S "christian/$password@sredb1_high"
```

But when I do this, I get no results. Interacting with the terminal directly gets me what I want. What could I possibly be missing? Ideally I also want the header and any extra gibberish off because I intend to downstream process results

```
cbongior@cbongior-mac perspective % sqlplus -S "christian/$password@sredb1_high"                                 
select count(*) from christian.MY_TABLE;

  COUNT(*)
----------
       500

^C^C^D
cbongior@cbongior-mac perspective % echo 'select count(*) from christian.MY_TABLE;' 'exit' | sqlplus -S "christian/$password@sredb1_high"
cbongior@cbongior-mac perspective %
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$ row_count=$( sqlplus -s "christian/$password@sredb1_high" <<END_SQL
SET HEADING OFF FEEDBACK OFF NEWPAGE NONE VERIFY OFF 
select count(*) from christian.MY_TABLE;
END_SQL
)
$ echo $row_count
500
```

Comment: This is the best way. One quibble though, this will show the password on the command line, visible to anybody logged into the host who does a ps listing.  Better to do "sqlplus -s '/nolog' << END_SQL  and then on the first line "CONNECT christian/$password" ... then it's part of the stdin stream and not the command line

Comment: Can you also turn off those control characters it outputs? I'm extracting json and it doesn't like that. `jq -sre .
parse error: Invalid string: control characters from U+0000 through U+001F must be escaped at line 2, column 5`
If I put it through `tr -d` I'm ok

Comment: @PaulW not 100% correct. The credentials are shown in `ps` only for a few milliseconds when sqlplus starts, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385339/how-does-curl-protect-a-password-from-appearing-in-ps-output/385349 But, of course your comment is valid.

Comment: I don't get any control characters in the output, for me the code is working. Do you have a real example of your code? Note, you don't need `exit` in the SQL code, sqlplus terminates automatically.

Comment: Wernfried, you are assuming Linux. I just tested and while on Linux and AIX the arguments are hidden in ps, in HPUX and Sun/Solaris they are not. You can see the password in ps if you use env variables on the command line.

Comment: @PaulW yes, I was referring to Red Hat Linux. Obviously it depends on the Linux kernel.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this, if you want a one-liner

```
[oracle@xxxxx~]$ echo -e "select * from dual;\nexit" |sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 23.0.0.0.0 - Beta on Thu Mar 16 16:33:45 2023
Version 23.1.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2022, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 23c Enterprise Edition Release 23.0.0.0.0 - Beta
Version 23.1.0.0.0

SQL>
D
-
X

SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 23c Enterprise Edition Release 23.0.0.0.0 - Beta
Version 23.1.0.0.0
```

Comment: Ok, that works, but it's wild. This should work without embedding the \n, because that's how echo normally outputs it. How do you get rid of the header?

Comment: the 'exit' command should be on a line by itself, and -e and \n ensure that. To get rid of the header, add a -s to the sqlplus part of the command.